Xverse Wallet. Logs into an account with a different wallet
Such a disaster happened. I created an Xverse wallet on April 20, copied the address and sent Ordinals tokens to it (address - bc1p...). I logged in today, I was kicked out of my wallet and asked to enter a seed phrase, I entered it and logged in, but there was a different wallet number and there were no funds.
I've been reading forums all day, Google, I learned about BIP and how Bitcoin works in general, but I still haven't found an answer. Help me please.
P.S. I started putting different numbers in Sparrowallet here m/XX'/0'/0' - but I can't find it. Initially it sets 86, but it’s possible that when registering Xverse something else was specified for this wallet.
